# Plural or singular after a/two subject(s) refering to a group of people?

Tags: grammar

Which form of object should we use when a sentence have one or more subjects, and the subject may refer to a group of people.

Here are some examples I am confused about.

A1. Food service workers and hair stylists generally have **low salaries**.
A2. Food service workers and hair stylists generally have **a low salary**.

B1. Many astronauts have **a military background**.
B2. Many astronauts have **military backgrounds**.

C1. They work regularly to **keep their bodies strong**.
C2. They work regularly to **keep their body strong**.

D1. Athletes often have **short careers**.
D2. Athletes often have **a short career**.

E1. Doctors require **a university degree** and several years in medical school.
E2. Doctors require **university degrees** and several years in medical school.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible.  You can choose the singular if you mean "each X has a Y"

> Doctors need a university degree  (Each doctor needs one degree)
>
> Doctors need university degrees (Perhaps each doctor needs multiple degrees)

In this case you the first is better, since only one degree is actually needed.

However the singular can me understood to be a single shared item.

> The students had a TV that they put in the basement of their student house. (One shared TV)

To avoid this ambiguity, or in situations where there is no ambigutiy the plural is often preferred.

> The work to keep their bodies strong.

There is no possible misunderstanding of "their multiple bodies". Nevertheless, both singular and plural would be correct, meaningful and have the same meaning in this context.

Comment: Hi James K, thank you!!! It helps me a lot.